# WKWebView in SwiftUI - How do I switch the view when user interacts with the website?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, swiftui, wkwebview

My situation is the following: I have a SwiftUI application and want to display a WebView. When the user taps a certain button in that WebView I want the user to be redirected to the next (SwiftUI) view.
I use a UIViewRepresentable as this seems to be the current way to go for showing a WebView in SwiftUI because it's the bridge to UIKit.
The problem is: UIViewRepresentable has no **body**. So where do I tell the view to switch over? In usual SwiftUI views I would have a model which I'd update and then react on the model change in the body.

I set up an example in which https://www.google.com is rendered in the WebView. When the user sends a search query the coordinator is called which calls a function of the UIViewRepresentable:

**View** - This is the view that should react on the model changes by displaying another view (implemented with *NavigationLinks*)

```
import SwiftUI

struct WebviewContainer: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: WebviewModel = WebviewModel()
    var body: some View {
        return NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: LoginView(), isActive: $model.loggedOut) {
                    EmptyView()
                }.isDetailLink(false)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text(""))
                .navigationBarHidden(self.model.navbarHidden)

                NavigationLink(destination: CameraView(model: self.model), isActive: $model.shouldRedirectToCameraView) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text(""))
                .navigationBarHidden(self.model.navbarHidden)
                Webview(model: self.model)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UIViewControllerRepresentable** - This is necessary in order to use the WKWebview in SwiftUI context

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct Webview : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var model: WebviewModel

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> EmbeddedWebviewController {
        let webViewController = EmbeddedWebviewController(coordinator: context.coordinator)
        webViewController.loadUrl(URL(string:"https://www.google.com")!)

        return webViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: EmbeddedWebviewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Webview>) {

    }

    func startCamera() {
        model.startCamera()
    }
}
```

**UIViewController** - The WKNavigationDelegate that reacts on the click on "Google Search" and calls the coordinator

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class EmbeddedWebviewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webview: WKWebView
    var router: WebviewRouter? = nil

    public var delegate: Coordinator? = nil

    init(coordinator: Coordinator) {
        self.delegate = coordinator
        self.webview = WKWebView()
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.webview = WKWebView()
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    public func loadUrl(_ url: URL) {
        webview.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

    override func loadView() {
        self.webview.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webview
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
        guard let url = (navigationResponse.response as! HTTPURLResponse).url else {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }

        if url.absoluteString.starts(with: "https://www.google.com/search?") {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            self.delegate?.startCamera(sender: self.webview)
        }
        else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

**Coordinator** - Bridge between *WKNavigationDelegate* and *UIViewRepresentable*

```
import Foundation
import WebKit

class Coordinator: NSObject {
    var webview: Webview

    init(_ webview: Webview) {
        self.webview = webview
    }

    @objc func startCamera(sender: WKWebView) {
        webview.startCamera()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I now have a View with a model (**@ObservedObject**). This model is given to the **UIViewControllerRepresentable**. When the user clicks "Google Search", **UIViewControllerRepresentable** successfully calls **model.startCamera()**. However, this change of the model is not reflected in the **WebviewContainer**. Why is that? Isn't that the whole purpose of **@ObservedObject**s?

Comment: You need to pass into your Webview some observable object (eg. via `@ObservedObject` or `@EnvironmentObject`) and in `doSomething` change some `@Published` property, depending on which value your ContentView shows (or navigates to) some other View.

Comment: Could you share the rest of the code? I can not scrape together a working example

Comment: What parts of the code are missing? How can I help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay now, I figured it out after having a quite intense debug session:

1.) The code I've presented in this post does indeed work. **It was only problematic in the context of my surrounding code**.

2.) The only provided answer so far **does not fix anything**. Just because it's already working and has nothing to do with code not being executed on the main thread (although I certainly agree, that this should be done for actions that affect the UI).

3.) In my case the problem was in the view that leads to **WebviewContainer**. In that view I had a model that was changing its values in an API call. On success it decides to redirect to **WebviewContainer** in case of failure it doesn't. So far so good. However, I was doing the model change in the **if** and should have prevented it in **else**. I was missing the else so for a blink of a second it was doing the right thing and then switching back. This was hard to debug because when I watched the model, everything was finde. The only thing that was strange was that the constructor of the model was called twice.

I am sorry that in this case I can not give the bounty to the given answer (you will get an upvote for the time invested.

Thank you very much! Learning: next time try to isolate the issue as much as I can in order to decrease the side effects of the rest of my application code.

Answer (score 5):

I added a `Model` to the provided code, which is updated when the `startCamera()` function is called. `@Published` variables should be updated on the UI thread since in most cases they change UI state which causes the UI to update.

Here is the full example:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import WebKit

class Coordinator: NSObject {
    var webview: Webview

    init(_ webview: Webview) {
        self.webview = webview
    }

    @objc func startCamera(sender: WKWebView) {
        webview.startCamera()
    }
}

class EmbeddedWebviewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webview: WKWebView
    //var router: WebviewRouter? = nil

    public var delegate: Coordinator? = nil

    init(coordinator: Coordinator) {
        self.delegate = coordinator
        self.webview = WKWebView()
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.webview = WKWebView()
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    public func loadUrl(_ url: URL) {
        webview.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

    override func loadView() {
        self.webview.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webview
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
        guard let url = (navigationResponse.response as! HTTPURLResponse).url else {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }

        if url.absoluteString.starts(with: "https://www.google.com/search?") {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            self.delegate?.startCamera(sender: self.webview)
        }
        else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

class WebviewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loggedOut: Bool = false
    @Published var shouldRedirectToCameraView: Bool = false
    @Published var navbarHidden: Bool = false
    func startCamera() {
        print("Started Camera")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.shouldRedirectToCameraView.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct Webview : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var model: WebviewModel

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> EmbeddedWebviewController {
        let webViewController = EmbeddedWebviewController(coordinator: context.coordinator)
        webViewController.loadUrl(URL(string:"https://www.google.com")!)

        return webViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: EmbeddedWebviewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Webview>) {

    }

    func startCamera() {
        model.startCamera()
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Login")
    }
}

struct CameraView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: WebviewModel
    var body: some View {
        Text("CameraView")
    }
}

struct WebviewContainer: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: WebviewModel = WebviewModel()
    var body: some View {
        return NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: LoginView(), isActive: $model.loggedOut) {
                    EmptyView()
                }.isDetailLink(false)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Hallo"))
                .navigationBarHidden(self.model.navbarHidden)

                NavigationLink(destination: CameraView(model: self.model), isActive: $model.shouldRedirectToCameraView) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text(""))
                .navigationBarHidden(self.model.navbarHidden)
                Webview(model: self.model)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        WebviewContainer()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: Demo]

I hope this helps.

Comment: So the only change you made was wrapping the modification of the variable in a wrapper that tells its body to be executed on the main thread?
I'm sorry, but this does not work for me :(. I see the print ("started Camera") on the console but the view won't switch.
Actually I would be surprised if this was necessary. DispatchQueue is a class that belongs to UIKit whereas the View to be presented is made with SwiftUI. But maybe I am missing any other change you made? Can you please elaborate? :) Thank you!

Comment: Well the changes of a `@Published` variable need to be performed on the UI thread since they manipulate the view.

Comment: @Schnodderbalken i added the complete example ... when i search something and press the search Icon it moves to the `CameraView`

Comment: I wrote an answer myself! Thank you for your effort.